# Django CBV - Formsets : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, formset

I'm working with Django CBV and I'm trying to use formsets for the first time.
I would like to fill two forms in the same time with a Foreign Key as common element between both.

I have 2 models :

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('title'), null=False, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('description'), null=True)
    download_limit = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('download limit'), null=True)
    time_limit = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('expiration delay'), null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=_('category'), null=False)
    nb_document = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('number of document'), default=0)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('creation date'), null=False)
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('modification date'), null=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('publication')
        verbose_name_plural = _('publication')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"


class Document(models.Model):

    FORMAT_CHOICES = (
        ('pdf', 'pdf'),
        ('epub', 'epub'),
    )
    age_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, verbose_name=_('publication ID'), unique=True, default='')
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name=_('language'), null=False)
    format = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=_('format'), choices=FORMAT_CHOICES, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('title'), null=False)
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, verbose_name=_('publication'), null=False, related_name='documents')
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='media/', validators=[validate_file_extension])
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('creation date'), null=False)
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('modification date'), null=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('document')
        verbose_name_plural = _('document')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.age_id} : {self.title} - {self.publication}"
```

I defined formset in my forms python file :

```
class PublicationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].empty_label = _('Select a category')  # Modify initial empty_label

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ['title', 'category']


class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['publication', 'age_id', 'language', 'format', 'title', 'upload']


DocumentFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Publication, Document, form=DocumentForm, extra=1)
```

And the most important thing, my view is defined inside a cruds.py file like this :

```
class PublicationCreateView(AgeCreateView):

    model = Publication
    template_name = 'app/publication_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PublicationCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.POST :
            context['document_form'] = DocumentFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            context['document_form'] = DocumentFormSet()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        document = context['document_form']
        if document.is_valid():
            document.instance = self.object
            document.save()
        return super(PublicationCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('publication-list-crud')




class PublicationCRUDView(MainConfigCRUDManager):
    """ CRUD views for Publication """
    model = Publication
    default_sort_params = ('category', 'asc')

    templates = {'create': 'app/publication_form.html'}

    custom_views = {'create': PublicationCreateView}

    #queryset = Publication.objects.annotate(nb_documents=Count('documents'))

    # Configuration of fields
    search_fields = ['category', 'title']
    list_fields = ['category', 'title', 'creation_date', 'modification_date', 'nb_document']
    update_fields = ['category', 'title']


class DocumentCRUDView(MainConfigCRUDManager):
    """ CRUD views for Document """
    model = Document
    default_sort_params = ('title', 'asc')

    templates = {'create': 'app/publication_form.html'}

    custom_views = {'create': PublicationCreateView}

    # Configuration of fields
    search_fields = ['age_id', 'title', 'language', 'publication_id.title', 'format']
    list_fields = ['age_id', 'title', 'publication', 'language', 'format']
    update_fields = ['publication', 'age_id', 'title', 'language', 'format', 'upload']
```

The template is well displayed, with common formset, but when I would like to submit this combined form, I get this issue :

> Exception Value:   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

And this is the Traceback :

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py"
>   in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py"
>   in dispatch
>     56.         return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py"
>   in dispatch
>     116.         return super(UserPassesTestMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py"
>   in post
>     217.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py"
>   in post
>     183.             return self.form_valid(form)
>
> File
>   "/home/Bureau/Projets/Publication/publication/src/web/app/cruds.py"
>   in form_valid
>     49.             document.save()
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py"
>   in save
>     666.         return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py"
>   in save_new_objects
>     800.             self.new_objects.append(self.save_new(form, commit=commit))
>
> File
>   "/home/.pyenv/versions/Publication3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py"
>   in save_new
>     946.         pk_value = getattr(self.instance, self.fk.remote_field.field_name)
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /crud/publication/create/ Exception
>   Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

I don't understand pretty well where the `id` is defined and How I can solve this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, but I don't know why it works now and not before.

The previous `form_valid()` function :

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        document = context['document_form']
        if document.is_valid():
            document.instance = self.object
            document.save()
        return super(PublicationCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

This my new `form_valid()` function :

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    document = context['document_form']
    if document.is_valid():
        self.object = form.save() #I added this line
        document.instance = self.object
        document.save()
    return super(PublicationCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Do you understand what the exception tells you? The code is trying to access the field "id" of a variable that has type NoneType, meaning the value is `None` (== null, undefined). You usually solve that by making sure your relevant variables actually contain values instead of `None`... which is what you have done in your answer by assigning `document.instance`.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for this explanation ! I have to look deeper about `.instance` in order to see in which case I have to or I could use this.